# Wait for event before loading javascript listener

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript set up to do a simple calculation on a form then place the value in another form field - this works fine on its own. However the page I need it to work on doesn't load the form until a button is clicked (wpsc_load_new_create_ticket_btn), so when the script loads on the page it can't find the event listeners (cost and quantity) and seems to give up on the script at that stage, even when the button is clicked. Is there a way to make the javascript not load until the button has been clicked?  I've tried with an event listener at the top with no success.

```
document.getElementById("wpsc_load_new_create_ticket_btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  cost.addEventListener("input", function multiply() {
    number1 = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
    number2 = document.getElementById("cost").value;
    console.log(number1 * number2);
    total = number1 * number2
    document.getElementById("total-claim-amount").value = total;
  });
  quantity.addEventListener("input", function multiply() {
    number1 = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
    number2 = document.getElementById("cost").value;
    console.log(number1 * number2);
    total = number1 * number2
    document.getElementById("total-claim-amount").value = total;
  });
});
```

Comment: You can use `setInterval` to periodically check if the form has been loaded into the DOM before proceeding

Comment: You can add a event listener for DOM modification to being notified when the form is created, with the object "MutationObserver" so you attach an observer on the parent of the form ( or maybe the body ) and check if the form is created in the callback .. etc.
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: Thanks guys, I've gone with setInterval, seems to the job, but will look into MutationObserver as well...